# Can I prevent panning Leaflet map out of the world's edge?

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

Is there a way to limit panning out of the world's edge? On this picture, brown is the world, grey is emptiness. I want to make it impossible to pan like this.

[image: out of this world]

Comment: This is possible, check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187161/bounding-view-of-a-leaflet-js-image-map-to-a-landscape-viewport

Comment: Thank you! But is it possible to make it not to go back after panning over limits, but to make it block panning when reaching limits?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Leaflet allows you to control how much the map resists being dragged out of bounds with the `maxBoundsViscosity` option (value: 0 to 1). Setting it to maximum disables dragging out of bounds entirely.

```js
var map = new L.Map('map', {
  center: bounds.getCenter(),
  zoom: 5,
  layers: [osm],
  maxBounds: bounds,
  maxBoundsViscosity: 1.0
});
```

This [feature](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1673) is available in 1.0.0. The [relevant pull request](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/3510) includes [a working example](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.0.0/debug/map/max-bounds-bouncy.html):

```js
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  osm1 = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: osmAttrib
  }),
  osm2 = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: osmAttrib
  }),
  bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(new L.LatLng(49.5, -11.3), new L.LatLng(61.2, 2.5));

var map1 = new L.Map('map1', {
  center: bounds.getCenter(),
  zoom: 5,
  layers: [osm1],
  maxBounds: bounds,
  maxBoundsViscosity: 0.75
});

var map2 = new L.Map('map2', {
  center: bounds.getCenter(),
  zoom: 5,
  layers: [osm2],
  maxBounds: bounds,
  maxBoundsViscosity: 1.0
});

var latlngs = L.rectangle(bounds).getLatLngs();
L.polyline(latlngs[0].concat(latlngs[0][0])).addTo(map1);
L.polyline(latlngs[0].concat(latlngs[0][0])).addTo(map2);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<h1>Left: Bouncy maxBounds. Right: Not bouncy.</h1>

<div id="map1" style="float: left; width:45%; height: 80%;"></div>
<div id="map2" style="float: left; width:45%; height: 80%;"></div>
```

Comment: Is this option still working ? I am not able to do something similar with mapbox

Comment: @gsuresh92 Not for mapbox. At this point [mapbox is using leaflet 0.7.7](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js/blob/34e4610dcca34152188b1a57cb4d3dab0db00a96/package.json), but this feature is in 1.0-beta1 and later.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this doesn't seem to work in rc3.

Comment: @catbadger Thanks. Looks like they refactored and [moved that option](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/4449). The [debug example](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/3a2106b2cc16b4a1f722e92c93c19552a6c4de57/debug/map/max-bounds-bouncy.html) for that option no longer works though; I'll check to see if it's a regression or not.

Comment: @catbadger I was mistaken, looks like the [debug example for rc3](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.0.0-rc.3/debug/map/max-bounds-bouncy.html) still works. Is this what you expect?

Answer (score 36):

This is how I resolved it for the world map

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 3);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

var southWest = L.latLng(-89.98155760646617, -180),
northEast = L.latLng(89.99346179538875, 180);
var bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
map.on('drag', function() {
    map.panInsideBounds(bounds, { animate: false });
});
```

See working example both for **version .7.0.7** http://jsfiddle.net/exqar2w4/18/ and for **version 1.0.3** http://jsfiddle.net/exqar2w4/20/

Comment: Is there a Standart way or a Leaflet Function to make this?

Comment: not exactly by default but what's in the answer is A way

Comment: Thanks for the answer this worked great. Any reason for making the lats so specific? I tried this and it works even when `[ -90, -180 ]`

Comment: @hughjdavey dunno just got those coords when positioned the globe, but yeah 90 works too obviously

Comment: `map.on('drag', function() {
    map.panInsideBounds(bounds, { animate: false });
});`.  This is what I was looking for to stop the bounce effect.  Thank you !

Comment: It works great but how to also prevent map going out of bounds on zoom out?

Comment: @SlawomirJakubek set a max min zoom out

Answer (score 14):

I use `react-leaflet` so syntax slightly different to above, but thought it would be helpful to show some sensible bounds to use (none of the answers above do that).

```
import Leaflet from 'leaflet'
import { Map as LeafletMap} from 'react-leaflet'

// Set map bounds.
// Allow scroll over the international date line, so users can comfortably zoom into locations near the date line.
const corner1 = Leaflet.latLng(-90, -200)
const corner2 = Leaflet.latLng(90, 200)
const bounds = Leaflet.latLngBounds(corner1, corner2)
```

Which is then rendered as...

```
<LeafletMap
  maxBoundsViscosity={1.0}
  maxBounds={bounds}
  {...otherProps}
>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I'm looking for