# Restrict Mapbox Zooming

Tags: google-maps, mapbox

I'm new to mapbox and trying to put one on my website. How can we ensure that it doesn't zoom out smaller than the div containing the map itself. Currently, it zooms out to level 1, leaving white spaces on all the sides.

I have used the following code

```
<style>
    #map {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 50%; // This is the aspect ratio
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>

<section id="content">
    <div id="map"></div>
</section>
```

I'm also attaching a snapshot to illustrate the problem...
[image]

Comment: Are you using the Google Maps Javascript API v3?  How are you creating the content of your "map" div?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm using Mapbox to create the map which is L.mapbox.map('map')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation for Mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.4.0/l-map-class/) you can set the `minZoom` (Map State Options):

> **minZoom**: Minimum zoom level of the map. Overrides any minZoom set on map layers.

If you were using [Mapbox GL JS](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/), you could use the `options.minZoom` parameter:

> **options.minZoom** (default 0)   The minimum zoom level of the map (1-20).

Comment: Great. Option.minZoom indeed solved the problem. I'm however still able to drag the map around which shows the white background again. Is there a way to stop dragging beyond the container?

Comment: You can use the `maxBounds` option that restricts the view to the given bounds

Comment: Indeed! Not sure if I did correct though. I set the bound extremes as [-85, -180],[85,180]. On dragging, the map springs back to the original container bounds.

Comment: Is there a way to change viscocity of dragging beyond the container for Mapbox? There is an option for Maps, but cannot find a way out for L.mapbox.map.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155017/can-i-prevent-panning-leaflet-map-out-of-the-world-edge) shows an example for L.map, but not sure how to use for L.mapbox.mapSorry, but a newbie here :(